# InstantApps.showInstallPrompt - Item not found (with Retry option)

Tags: android, android-support-library, deep-linking, android-instant-apps

I've been working on an instant app to go along with my existing application.  When I reach a certain point in the instant app, I try and prompt the user to download the full application from the playstore, however, I instead receive a dialog saying "**Item not found**", with a button that says "**Retry**".

I've been reading these docs here: [Developer reference > instantapps.InstantApps](https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/reference.html#instantapps.InstantApps) 
but they are kind of unclear to me.

**From the docs:** "*If your instant app minSdkVersion is 26 or higher, you can use framework methods directly instead of using the compatibility library.*"

My `minSdk version` as of now is 16 (don't think this is right, pretty certain instant apps `minsdk` is 21 or something, i just made the minimum to be the same as my current application).

Anyways, does the `minSdkVersion` have to be 26 in order for the `showInstallPrompt` method to work? I am not exactly sure what the docs mean when they say i can use the compatibility library, I imagine this is one of the support libraries, but i cannot be certain as to which one.

My Current supportVersion is 27.1.1, and includes the following libraries:

```
  compile "com.android.support:transition:$supportVersion"
  compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportVersion"
  compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$supportVersion"
  compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$supportVersion"
  compile "com.android.support:support-v13:$supportVersion"
  compile "com.android.support:design:$supportVersion"
  compile "com.android.support:support-v4:$supportVersion"
  compile "com.android.support:support-v13:$supportVersion"
  compile "com.android.support:support-annotations:$supportVersion"
```

I also include the instantApps library as well, as specified in the docs

```
compile 'com.google.android.instantapps:instantapps:1.1.0'
```

and my buildToolsVersion is 27.0.3.  App's target sdk is 27, with min of 16.

Code to show install prompt:

```
myIntent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class)
        .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
        .putExtras(bundle);
InstantApps.showInstallPrompt(this, myIntent, 0, "InstantApp");
```

The bundle in the intent contains a single boolean value.

If anyone knows of a way to make this work without changing the minSdk to 26, that would be awesome. Otherwise i may have to do some other type of custom solution.

Comment: NOTE: Just tried changing my minSdk to 26 and still received the Item not found dialog

Comment: Can you post your full code for the `showInstallPrompt`, including the `myIntent`? Is your installed-app published to Release? And do you see anything in the logs?

Comment: Yeah I'll add the intent to the original post.  And I have a previous version on the playstore, but it isn't setup with instant apps. Does it need to be in order for that dialog to work?  And I was running on the debug build variant.  Does it need to be ran on release or something? Gonna check the logs now.

Comment: Ahhhhh.. Okay great call on checking the logs.  It says there was an error loading the given package name, because i add an extra applicationId suffix to my debug build variant. so it looks it appears that is why resource cannot be found

Comment: Yup that did it.  Thank you for the help.